# Getting 'the next' column in Google sheets/scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to edit a spreedsheet in sheets each time a form is filled in.

**The situation:** People fill in the form, and I want to send a confirmation email based on their replies.

**Problem:** I would like to put a 'message sent' text in the last form field +1. So I was looking at a way to get the last column +1 in A1notation. Anyone know how to do it? I've looked everywhere but can't find a solution, thanks!

Comment: See the [Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) for an example of exactly what you want, with one exception.  Once complete you need to make the sendEmails function an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on the form submission.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I had already come across this one, and experimented with it. My only drawback is that it if i do that (trigger on form submission) it will send emails to all the records each time a new form is submitted

Comment: I thought that code had a check for an Action column or other items where it placed an Email Sent message. Sorry.  Add a column to the end of the Form columns and give it a name, then as the function loops through the data, add a test for that column to be blank.  After sending the email, add data to the column so your test can then skip this line.  Basically your 'Message Sent' text.  It just goes into a column that is not part of the form.

Comment: Perhaps this [add-on] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-notifications-for-f/acknfdkglemcidajjmehljifccmflhkm will do the trick:   However, if you want to code it yourself, please insert/paste the code you already have!